# Is there a way to draw a numbered line on form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to draw a line on the form which have scales on it from (1-10)
Is it possible?
If yes please help me out?

here is the code for drawing a simple line on the form

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 190, 210, 350, 210)
```

Comment: You already know how to draw a line. Next step is to learn [how to draw a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) and how to use a [for...next statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will  help you

```
Dim str as string = "1"
e.graphics.drawstring(str,Font, Brushes.Black, 185, 210)
```

this will draw a string 1 and so on you can draw from 1-10